# unable to import products in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

The first time I am hosting my Magento 2 version(2.3.4) website, I am facing here while uploading the product!

the error is :

1. Invalid value in Website column (website does not exist?) in a row(s): 1

[image: error image]

and this is my CSV file

[image: cdvsheet]

I have downloaded this sample file from the import section only 
[my upload file](http://trdev.com.au/exdata/)

[image: sample file]

I have tried many solutions on the internet

what is the problem here, What I suppose to give value for 'product_websites' ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62068176/edit) the question and add a **raw** version of your CSV file!

Comment: sure @0stone0  .

Comment: please check my file http://trdev.com.au/exdata/

Comment: @0stone0 did you check the file , i have updated

Comment: I've checked the file, It looks fine to me, maybe it had something to do with the field separators. I guess you should ask your question on [Magento StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thank you @0stone0 , i posted , also what will be field seprartors for CSV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of sample file , please create one product from backend and export that product and use that sample file !

this fix my problem